# preg_replace to convert a user input string to a link pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to convert user input string

> "something ... un// important ,,, like-this"

to

"something-un-important-like-this"

So basically remove all recurring special characters with "-". I've googled and came to this

```
preg_replace('/[-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/s', '-', strtolower($string)));
```

I'm curious as to know if this can be done with a single preg_replace().

Just to clear things out:
replace all special characters and blank space with a hyphen(-). If more occurrence appear consecutively replace them with single hyphen

My solution works perfectly as I want to but I'm looking to do the same in a single call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question yesterday, but I don't have it at hand.

In your current *first* pattern:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

you're looking for a single character only. If you make that a greedy match for one or more, the regular expression engine will automatically replace multiple of these with a single one:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
              ^- + = one or more
```

You then still have the problem that existing `-` inside the string are not caught, so you need to take them out of the "not-in" character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

This then should do it:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+/s', '-', strtolower($string));
```

And as it's only lowercase, you do not need to look for `A-Z` as well, just another reduction:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/s', '-', strtolower($string));
```

See as well *Repetition*  and/or *Quantifiers* of which the `+` is one of (see [*Repetition<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.repetition.php); [*Repetition with Star and Plus<sup>­regular-expressions.info</sup>*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

Also if you take a look at the [modifiers<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), you'll see that the *s (PCRE_DOTALL)* modifier is not necessary:

```
$urlSlug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/', '-', strtolower($string));
```

Hope this helps and explains you a little about the regular expression you're using and also where you can find further documentation which is always helpful.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. regex sometimes just goes over my head.

Comment: it's a powerful tool, and nowadays there is also documentation in the php manual in the [preg module (PCRE)](http://php.net/pcre). A good read into regular expressions is http://regular-expressions.info/, it's nicely divide and in my eyes an exceptional good resource.

Comment: Thank you for those links will definitely go through those later.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/s', '-', strtolower($string));
```